# Splitting String with Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, split

Hi
I really don't understand Regular Expressions :P

This is the input string:

```
"{\"Name\", \"Surname\", \"Age\", \"Other string with letters and numbers\"}"
```

And this is the output array of strings that i want:

- Name;
- Surname;
- Age;
- Other string with letters and numbers

In other words, i have to eliminate `"`, `{` and `,`

Comment: Is that really a string? It looks like an array to me.

Comment: I think he means "{\"Name\", \"Surname\", \"Age\", \"Other string with letters and numbers\"}"

Comment: Any character list can be a string.. if he says this is the string, maybe this is the string!

Comment: yes of course it was a string :D i hope that now is clearer ;)

Comment: Where's this data coming from? Is it JSON? If so, there are several libraries out there to aid in marshalling/unmarshalling JSON content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will match all the terms you specify:

`\"(.*?)\"`

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/A91DetXakU

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str = "{\"Name\", \"Surname\", \"Age\", \"Other string with letters and numbers\"}";
    String strArr[] = str.replaceAll("\\}|\\{|\"", "").split(",");
    for (String tmpStr : strArr) {
        System.out.println(tmpStr);

    }
```

Output:

> Name
>    Surname
>    Age
>    Other string with letters and numbers

- [IdeOneDemo](http://ideone.com/mm44Q)

Comment: You've forgotten to remove double quotes from the input string

Comment: Perhaps he only asked for a regex because he didn't know there's a perfectly good `split()` method? :)

Comment: yes, i knew about the String's methods :) but i was searching for regex

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with `yourString.split("[\\", {}]");`

Comment: Nothing. That is perfectly fine sir.